# Can I register domain name and SSL certificate with different registrars?

Tags: domains, security-certificate

I want to purchase an SSL Certificate for one of the ecommerce website, I already have the domain name and website site is already running on that domain.

Now I want to buy SSL for the same domain/website.

My domain is with GoDaddy and my hosting is with Resellerclub.

Does it make any difference if both of them are registered with different registrars?

OR

Do I have to make them available on same single registrar?

Comment: Please do not use the formatting tools incorrectly.

Comment: No, it does not matter. You can buy your domain from one company and SSL certificate from another. In fact, I'd bet the majority of site owners do just that.

Comment: Okay thank you for the prompt reply, i asked this because of the godaddy phone representative told me, that you need to transfer the domain to godaddy in order to buy the SSL certificated then only you will be able to use it.

Comment: The person must be new @ GoDaddy and what he/she said is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

But John's already said that in the comment.

As far as SSL is concerned, it makes no difference whatsoever.

However, if you buy the certificate and your hosting from the same vendor, they may 'install' it for you automatically.

The domain only gets validated and, as such, does not play a part in the installation.

So, in a nutshell, it may be convenient to buy the SSL certificate from your host, but you can have the domain, hosting and SSL from completely different vendors.